# React.js logging before operation is finished

Tags: reactjs

```
   onReaderLoad = (e) => {
    var obj =JSON.parse(e.target.result)
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      datasource: [...prevState.datasource, obj]
    }))
  }

  ReadFiles = () => {
    let files = this.state.json_files;

    for (let i of files){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = this.onReaderLoad;
      reader.readAsText(i);
    }

    console.log(this.state.datasource)

  }


  getfolder = (e) => {
    var files = e.target.files;
    this.setState({
      json_files: files
    }, () => this.ReadFiles())    
  }


                  <input type="file" onChange={this.getfolder} multiple accept=".json" />
```

Here i am sharing my code.

What i am trying to do is  i am reading all the **json** files from user input and looping them and storing it to react state.
Then inside **ReadFiles()** function i am logging the state data. But it is always coming empty data.

I think it calling first and then going to the loop.

I wants to log the **datasource** data from state inside **ReadFiles()** function after all Looping operation is done

Is there any way to do that ?

Please have a  look

Comment: the state is not updated yet when you log. Why do you log it ?

Comment: I have to call anothe function and send data immidietly after this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No, I wants to log after the loop

Comment: Then use the data directly, not the state. If you use the state, then you cannot call the function immediately after, you need to wait for react to update the component

Comment: There will be multiple data and i am readding them inside another function so can't use data directly

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `instance variable` in this case to keep track of whether you are processing last file or not. Once you know that last file is being processed, you can set `doNextStep` to `true` in `state` from callback of last processed file. Then in `componentDidUpdate`, you can do next step(i.e. `console log or anything else`).

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // to keep track of if last file is being processed
    this.lastFile = false;
    
    // doNextStep will tell us that all setState operations are completed or not
    this.state = {
      doNextStep: false,
    }
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if(prevState.doNextStep !== this.state.doNextStep && this.state.doNextStep) {
      console.log(this.state.datasource)
      }
    }
    
         
   onReaderLoad = (e) => {
  var obj =JSON.parse(e.target.result)
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    datasource: [...prevState.datasource, obj]
  }), 
  () => if(this.lastFile)) this.setState({doNextStep: true}))
  }
    
  ReadFiles = () => {
    let files = this.state.json_files;

    for (i=0; i<files.length; i++){
      if(i == files.length - 1) this.lastFile = true
      else this.lastFile = false
      
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = this.onReaderLoad;
      reader.readAsText(i);
      
    }
  }
        }
```

Comment: @soubhagya-pradhan Did above approach solve your problem?

Comment: @soubhagya-pradhan Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answer if it helped you.